# Textview in side tableview overwriting in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using the following code to show some labels and a textview in a tableview. But the problem is some textviews overwriting at some unwanted places while scrolling. Please help me . Thanks in advance

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle                                         =   UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    if (indexPath.row==0) 
    {
        UILabel *Sender = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 200, 20)];
        Sender.text=@"From Time";
        Sender.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:159.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]; 
        Sender.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:16];
        [cell addSubview:Sender];
        [Sender release];  

    }

    if (indexPath.row==1) 
    {
        UILabel *Sender = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 200, 20)];
        Sender.text=@"Sender";
        Sender.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:159.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]; 
        Sender.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:16];
        [cell addSubview:Sender];
        [Sender release];  
        UILabel *Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 35, 200, 20)];
        Label.text=@"Achuthananthan";
        Label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:14];
        [cell addSubview:Label];
        [Label release]; 
    }
    if (indexPath.row==2) 
    {
        UILabel *Agenda = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 200, 20)];
        Agenda.text=@"Agenda";
        Agenda.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:159.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]; 
        Agenda.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:16];

        [cell addSubview:Agenda];
        [Agenda release]; 
        UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 120)];
        textView.editable=NO;
        textView.text=[NSString stringWithString:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda."];
        textView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:14];
        [cell addSubview:textView];

        [textView release];

    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code...

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle =   UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

 UILabel *Sender = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 200, 20)];
     [sender setTag:500];
Sender.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:16];
    Sender.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:159.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]; 
    [cell addSubview:Sender];
    [Sender release];  

    UILabel *Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 35, 200, 20)];
    Label.text=@"Achuthananthan";
    Label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:14];
    [Label setTag:600];
    [cell addSubview:Label];
    [Label release]; 

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 120)];
    textView.editable=NO;
[Label setTag:700];
    textView.text=[NSString stringWithString:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda."];
    textView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:14];
    [cell addSubview:textView];
    [textView release];

}

UILabel *firstLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:500];
UILabel *SecondLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:600];
UITextView *firstText = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:700];

if (indexPath.row==0) 
{

    firstLabel.text=@"From Time";
[SecondLabel setHidden:Yes];
[firstText setHidden:Yes];

}

if (indexPath.row==1) 
{

    firstLabel.text=@"Sender";
[SecondLabel setHidden:NO];
[firstText setHidden:Yes];

}
if (indexPath.row==2) 
{
    firstLabel.text=@"Agenda";
[SecondLabel setHidden:Yes];
[firstText setHidden:NO]; 
}
return cell;
 }
```

Comment: is the content (label and text view)showing over cells or not??

Answer (score 0):

Move the code that adds the views inside the `if (cell == nil) {` section

For example if you want to add a `UILabel` do the following

```
UILabel *label;
if (cell == nil) {
    //create the cell
    //Create the label
    //Give the label a tag
    label.tag = 111; //for example
    //add label to the cell
    [cell.contentView addSubView:label];
}

//Now get the label of the cell
label = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:111];
```

Repeat this for all the UILabels and other Views you want to add to the cell

Comment: now columns are empty.Not working .Any way thanks for your answer

Comment: @Melbourne: I think you must not have used it correctly..otherwise it would have solved the problem.Can you show the new code that you have iomplemented?