# Tableviewcell's image sometimes displays image from other row just for a moment when scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have a ImageDownloader class with a function that downloads image with GCD:

```
- (void) downloadImageFromURL:(NSURL *) url completionBlock:(void (^)(UIImage *image, NSError *error)) block {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *picture=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    if(picture) {
        block(picture, nil);
    } 
    else {
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"image_download_error" code:1 
                                         userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Can't fetch data" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]];
        block(nil, error);
    }

  });
}
```

My tableviewcell (defined in its own nib file) calls this function for every row like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//custom cell in nib file
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"contactsCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"contactsCell" owner:self options:nil]; //feedCell je ime nib fajla
    cell = contactsCell;
    self.contactsCell = nil;
}  

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    UIImageView *avatar=(UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
    avatar.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"petek.jpg"];
    UILabel *nameLabel= (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
    nameLabel.text=@"Some guy";
    UIButton *askBtn=(UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
    [askBtn setTitle:@"Ask" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [askBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
else {
    UIImageView *avatar=(UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
    ImageDownloader *idl=[[ImageDownloader alloc] init];
    NSURL *imageUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someImageUrl"];
    [idl downloadImageFromURL:imageUrl completionBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error)
     {
         if(!error) {
             dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                 avatar.image=image;
             });
         } else {
             NSLog(@"error %@", error);
         }

     }];
    UILabel *nameLabel= (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
    nameLabel.text=@"John Stockton";
    UIButton *followBtn=(UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
    [followBtn setTitle:@"Follow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [followBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

    return cell;    

}
```

Images for section 1 load correctly, but when scrolling, sometimes a row from section 1 has image from section 0 just for a few moments.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310145/textview-in-side-tableview-overwriting-in-iphone/11310304#11310304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are reusing the unique identifier for the row named `MyIdentifier`, it might be dequeuing the old row's image and then reloading the data.

You can rather use this instead if a static identifier like:

```
NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"contactsCell-%d-%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do `avatar.image = nil` before starting the download you will not have this problem. It's happening because there is a lag between when the cell comes on screen and when the cell's image finishes downloading.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView *avatar=(UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:1];`
don't ever carry any information in cells. they are reusable.